# Why can termius connect to ssh while nassh cannot

Tags: ssh, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have managed to get sshd running in Termux. I can connect to the sshd server using Termius. I tried to connect using nassh, but I'm getting a "Connection refused" message. Both apps are configured to connect to `localhost:8022`. I'm not even sure what to look at next on ChromeOS to understand why one would be able to connect while the other wouldn't.

I'm not sure what I'm not understanding or missing here. As far as I understand, "Connection refused" means nassh is getting `ECONNREFUSED` when trying to `connect()`. This would happen if there is nothing listening on a particular host:port. Clearly, I do have sshd listening; I can repeatedly connect to it using Termius; I get a shell that is obviously the Termux environment. Is there some network namespacing that is going on? Why would Termius be able to connect (with no additional permissions or extra setup afaicr) but not nassh?

For clarity, screenshots are below.

[Termius configuration connects to localhost:8022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O10d.png)
[nassh gets "Connection refused" for localhost:8022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhUpX.png)

Comment: I have also found that I can't seem to connect to any network service on localhost or 127.0.0.1 in Chrome. Other browsers seem to be okay. I have found  chrome://net-internals/#events and am hoping it gives me some better information.

Comment: Is chrome set to use a proxy server?

Comment: I have not configured a proxy server.

Comment: Re 1st @ShawnJ.Goff comment: Chrome can only connect to Android/Termux apps through a private IP address (find with ifconfig from Termux), but not localhost or 127.0.0.1.  Other Android apps (e.g. Firefox) can connect to Android apps (e.g. Termux running a program) at localhost.  Did you try connecting with nassh via the Android private IP address?